# Getting an error when creating an Azure security policy that audits NSGs that have no custom rules defined

Tags: azure

Trying to create a security policy in Azure that will audit NSGs that don't have any custom rules defined. When I go to save the definition, I get the following error:

*Creating policy definition 'NSG_Audit_Default_Policy_Only' in 'Tenant Root Group' failed. Failed to parse policy rule: 'Could not find member 'equals' on object of type 'CountExpressionDefinition'. Path 'count.equals'.'.*

What am I doing wrong? I'm very new to Azure and creating policy definitions. TIA!

***9/7 Updated code*** Code below is flagging policies with defaults only as "compliant" and policies with custom as "non-compliant" the logic is flip-flopped. What am I missing?

```
 },
    "parameters": {},
    "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups"
          },
          {
            "not": {
              "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules[*].priority",
              "greaterOrEquals": 65000
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "audit"
      }
    }
  },
```

Pasted the code into the Policy Rule form in the portal and was expecting to be able to save it successfully then apply.

Answer (score 0):

> Trying to create a security policy in Azure that will audit NSGs that don't have any custom rules defined. When I go to save the definition.

Here is the updated `Azure Policy` to audit `NSGs` that don't have any custom rules defined.

```html
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups"
        },
        {
          "not": {
            "anyOf": [
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules[*].priority",
                "greaterOrEquals": 65000
              },
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules[*].access",
                "in": ["Allow", "Deny"]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "audit"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}
```

Once the policy is assigned, it will audit all `NSGs`. If there are no rules inside an `NSG`, it will mark it as non-compliant, and if there are any rules, it will mark it as compliant.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, this is not flagging my test NSGs. Is it because the policy is looking for a blank policy? I want it to flag NSGs that only have the default policies (e.g. numbered 65000 and above; default rules that can't be erased).

Comment: Hi @vb312, I have updated policy as per your requirement. Please check and confirm.

Comment: Thank you. This is still not working. It marks all NSGs as compliance even thought I've got a couple NSGs that only have default rules (priority 65000+) in the rule set.

Comment: I updated the code above with comments. It's marking is mixed up, it's flagging default-only policies as compliant and policies with custom rules as non-compliant. I suspect I need an additional condition? TIA!

Comment: Try this [policy](https://i.imgur.com/3AqAnBd.png) to check if any security rule within the **NSG** has a priority greater than or equal to **65000** and if it has an **"Allow"** or **"Deny" access**. If any of these conditions are met, the NSG is considered compliant. Otherwise, it will be marked as non-compliant

Comment: Thanks. That is not what I'm trying to do. I'm looking for NSG that ONLY has policy with priority >=6500, tag as non-compliant. Basically I need to find policy that has NO custom policies applied only default and tag as non-compliant. Thanks